# additive integral property

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, arithmetic, area

There's a common property of definite integrals:
$\int_a^bf(x) \, dx=\int_a^cf(x)\,dx+\int_c^bf(x)\,dx$.
I've often seen it said that $c$ must lie in the interval $[a,b]$. However, is this really the case?
I'm asking as a specialist mathematics high school teacher. All the examples I can think of, considering the integral as denoting the area under the curve, hold true for $c\notin[a,b]$ as well.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, c does not have to be in [a,b]

Comment: Well, $f$ may not be integrable or even defined outside $[a,b]$. But if it is, then the formula is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

**Assume $f$ is Riemann integrable over $\mathbb{R}$.**

Then, the derivative of the function
$$
\mathbb{R} \ni c \mapsto \int_a^cf(x)\,dx+\int_c^bf(x)\,dx \tag1
$$ is
$$
c \mapsto f(c)-f(c)\equiv0 \tag2
$$ thus $$
 c \mapsto \int_a^cf(x)\,dx+\int_c^bf(x)\,dx
$$ is a *constant function* over $\mathbb{R}$, putting $c=a$ gives

> $$
> \int_a^bf(x)\,dx=\int_a^cf(x)\,dx+\int_c^bf(x)\,dx, \quad \color{blue}{\forall \, c\, \in \,\mathbb{R}}.
> $$